# Properly align columns for rows that end early VBA/Excel

Tags: excel, vba

i have data that ends at different columns. the last 3 column of each row is always the same (url tag type).

1. What I want to do is find the row with the largest number of columns
   (in example below, bbcc. Columns would be G, H, I)
2. Move the last 3 columns of rows 1 & 3 so that they align in rows G, H, I.

Example data below-- I'm trying to move url under url category, tag under tag category, and type under type category.

Assistance or pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I am not quite sure how to go about this :(

name | color1 | color2 | color3 | color4 | color5 | url | tag | type

aabb | black  | brown  |  url1  |   tag1 |  type1

bbcc | green  | blue   | pink   | yellow | purple | url2| tag2| type2

ccdd | orange |   url3 |   tag3 |   type3

Comment: Looks like you imported a CSV and left *'Treat consecutive delimiters as one'* turned on. Go back and re-import the data correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** after OP's clarification

**edited 2** after OP's error occurrence

the *"run-time error 1004. application defined or run time defined error"* must be related to rows whose last non empty cell column index is smaller than three

so I put a check on this: rows whose last non empty cell column index is smaller than three will not be processed

you can try this code (see comments)

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim lastCol As Long, maxCol As Long, iCol As Long

    With Worksheets("Align") '<--| change "Align" to your actual sheet name
        Set rng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| get all columns "A" not empty cells
        ReDim lastCols(1 To rng.Count) As Long '<--| resize last column index array accordingly to the number of not empty cells

        For Each cell In rng '<--| loop through column "A" not empty cells
            iCol = iCol + 1 '<--| update last column index array index
            lastCols(iCol) = .Cells(cell.row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column '<--| update last column index array current index value
            If lastCols(iCol) > maxCol Then maxCol = lastCols(iCol) '<--| update maximum column index
        Next cell

        iCol = 1 '<--| initialize last column index array index
        For Each cell In rng '<--| loop through column "A" not empty cells
            If lastCols(iCol) < maxCol And lastCols(iCol) > 3 Then cell.Offset(, lastCols(iCol) - 3).Resize(, maxCol - lastCols(iCol)).Insert xlShiftToRight '<--| if current cell row has at least three not empty cells and the last one has smaller column index than maximum column index then shift current cell row last three cells to align left with maximum column index
            iCol = iCol + 1
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

but you may want to use this alternative that shift cells *values* rather then *cells* themselves:

```
Sub main()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim lastCol As Long, maxCol As Long, iCol As Long

    With Worksheets("Align") '<--| change "Align" to your actual sheet name
        Set rng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| get all columns "A" not empty cells
        ReDim lastCols(1 To rng.Count) As Long '<--| resize last column index array accordingly to the number of not empty cells

        For Each cell In rng '<--| loop through column "A" not empty cells
            iCol = iCol + 1 '<--| update last column index array index
            lastCols(iCol) = .Cells(cell.row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column '<--| update last column index array current index value
            If lastCols(iCol) > maxCol Then maxCol = lastCols(iCol) '<--| update maximum column index
        Next cell

        iCol = 1 '<--| initialize last column index array index
        For Each cell In rng '<--| loop through column "A" not empty cells
            If lastCols(iCol) < maxCol And lastCols(iCol) > 3 Then '<--|if current cell row has at least three not empty cells and the last one has smaller column index  than maximum column index
                With cell.Offset(, lastCols(iCol) - 3).Resize(, 3) '<--| reference current cell row last three cells
                    cell.Offset(, maxCol - 3).Resize(, 3).Value = .Value '<--|shift referenced cells values (not cells) to align left with maximum column index
                    .ClearContents '<--clear referenced cells
                End With
            End If
            iCol = iCol + 1 '<--| update last column index array index
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out with this. I tried this--it moves the entire row to the left most column of the longest row. Need to only move last 3 cells for each row.

Comment: its giving a run-time error 1004. application defined or run time defined error"

Comment: this works! shifting the cell values was a better way to go. thank you very much for your assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Sub AlignLast3Columns()
    Dim lColumn As Long, x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim Data()

    With Worksheets("After")
        x = .Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        y = .Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        Set Target = .Range("A1", .Cells(x, y))
    End With
    Data = Target.Value2
    lColumn = UBound(Data, 2)
    For x = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        If IsEmpty(Data(x, lColumn)) Then
            For y = lColumn To 1 Step -1
                If Not IsEmpty(Data(x, y)) Then
                    For z = 0 To 2
                        Data(x, lColumn - z) = Data(x, y - z)
                        Data(x, y - z) = ""
                    Next
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Target.Value2 = Data


End Sub
```