# Need to align data and eliminate blanks

Tags: vba

I have a data set from Column L through Column AA. I want all cells to move such that the last cell in each row moves to Column AA and the rest shift right such that all blank cells are gone. Could someone please assist with a VBA code? Thank you!

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim lastCol As Long, maxCol As Long, iCol As Long

With Worksheets("Align") '<--| change "Align" to your actual sheet name
    Set rng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| get all columns "A" not empty cells
    ReDim lastCols(1 To rng.Count) As Long '<--| resize last column index array accordingly to the number of not empty cells

    For Each cell In rng '<--| loop through column "A" not empty cells
        iCol = iCol + 1 '<--| update last column index array index
        lastCols(iCol) = .Cells(cell.row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column '<--| update last column index array current index value
        If lastCols(iCol) > maxCol Then maxCol = lastCols(iCol) '<--| update maximum column index
    Next cell

    iCol = 1 '<--| initialize last column index array index
    For Each cell In rng '<--| loop through column "A" not empty cells
        If lastCols(iCol) < maxCol And lastCols(iCol) > 3 Then cell.Offset(, lastCols(iCol) - 3).Resize(, maxCol - lastCols(iCol)).Insert xlShiftToRight '<--| if current cell row has at least three not empty cells and the last one has smaller column index than maximum column index then shift current cell row last three cells to align left with maximum column index
        iCol = iCol + 1
    Next cell
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack! Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You'll get some better help if you post what VBA you've already tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you  - I tried using the code from this previous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715877/properly-align-columns-for-rows-that-end-early-vba-excel 

The 1st response (1st code) aligns the last three cells of each row. I think if this was amended to remove that rule and just make sure all rows (within Columns L - Columns AA) perform the same action.

Comment: Please try to include **your** code as it is written, not by describing it (you may have bugs in it that aren't visible from your description). Include your code in the question.

Comment: Updated - appreciate the patience with this newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Sub main()

    Dim rw As Range, arr, arr2(), i, n, num

    Set rw = Worksheets("Align").Range("L2:AA2")
    num = rw.Cells.Count

    'run until row is empty
    Do While Application.CountA(rw) > 0

        arr = rw.Value                '<< pick up the row contents
        ReDim arr2(1 To 1, 1 To num)  '<< new array for consolidated values
        n = num
        For i = num To 1 Step -1      '<< loop backwards
            If Len(arr(1, i)) > 0 Then
                arr2(1, n) = arr(1, i)
                n = n - 1
            End If
        Next i

        With rw
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter   '<< added
            .NumberFormat = "@"               '<< added
            .Value = arr2                     '<< re-populate the row
        End With

        Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0)      '<< next row
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: this worked - thank you!

What would you add to get all cells to have cells "middle align" and stay in text format?